# Bit Manipulation: Add a bit to the left most corner of a sets of bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, byte, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

So let's say I had a set of bits in the following order:

00101 which obviously would be equal to 5

Would it be possible to add a 1 on the left corner of the sets of bits such that it would be 
100101 which would be equal to 37. (Using Bit Manipulation)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 00101 which obviously would be equal to 5
100101 which would be equal to 37
```

To solve this you need two values:

1. The bit value given above, here named `val`
2. The count of bits in the value (because it is not a regular value like 8,16,...), here named `len`

Then you can get the final value by using the following formula:

```
result = val | (1 << len)
```

In your case this would be

```
result = 00101b | (1 << 5d) = 00101b | 100000b = 100101b
```

---

In x86 assembly (Intel MASM syntax) this could be done like this

```
mov eax, val   ; EAX = 00000101
mov ecx, len   ; ECX = 5
mov edx, 1     ; EDX = 00000001
shl edx, cl    ; EDX = 00100000
or  eax, edx   ; EAX = 00100101
```